# Limit funtions for non subscriptions user.android

Tags: android, subscription, android-billing

I would like to create an app that can be subscriptions. If the user hasn't subscribed, they only have limited functions can use, when they subscribed, they will open the full functions.
How to do it on android? Can anyone tell me step by step? thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends of the application, for example, you could create an app with flavors, by default is free and another flavor to subscribers, so is necessary to installar de subscriber app... another approach is use an app and disabled the subscribers options by flag (if != subscriber, show defaultUI else show subsctiberUI)... another option is handle the state with a feature flag and using the bakcend... is necessary to know the roadmap to decide the best approach

Comment: do you mean build variants??

Comment: no, flavors (ProductFlavor) https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants?hl=es-419